# POSTGIS: TRIGGER insert into according max area

Tags: postgresql, postgis

i got no luck with following code.
I'am editing polygons in my database. It would be great if 
my new polygone gets from the backgroundlayer "polya" a specific value.
Unfortunatley it could be happen that my new layer doesn't care about the boundiers of the backgroundlayer. In this case it should takes the value
where the largest part of my edit intersects with the backgroundlayer.
I hope you can help me.

[Overview_QGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69C27.png)

```
BEGIN
    SELECT string_agg(polya."FOO1",', '))
    INTO NEW."FOO2"
    FROM "xyz" as polya
    WHERE                                       
   ST_AREA(ST_Intersection(NEW.the_geom,polya.the_geom))=GREATEST(ST_AREA(ST_Intersection(NEW.the_geom,polya.the_geom)));
    RETURN NEW;
   END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order the intersection polygons by the area in descent order and limit the result set to 1.

```
BEGIN

    SELECT polya.FOO1
    INTO   NEW.FOO2
    FROM   yxz as polya
    WHERE  ST_Intersects(NEW.the_geom,polya.the_geom)
    ORDER BY ST_Area(ST_Intersection(NEW.the_geom,polya.the_geom)) desc
    LIMIT 1;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your rapid response. If i understand correct: The first value is the largest area and the rest you cut off?